# Send out-of-band data using boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Like in gnu c, is there any way to send out-of-band data in boost.
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Out_002dof_002dBand-Data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the out of band flag: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/out_of_band_inline.html

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(my_context);
// set out of band option
boost::asio::socket_base::out_of_band_inline option(true);
socket.set_option(option);

// get out of band option
socket.get_option(option);
bool value = option.value();
```